# how to call the API from SkyBiometry in a python script

Tags: python, api, http, python-requests

I am new at stackoverflow and to programming with python and I am trying to get an emotion analyses for images from my hard disk by using the service of skybiometry.com. The example link of them is like: "http://api.skybiometry.com/fc/faces/detect.json?api_key=aa754b54b37&api_secret=4b3a4c6d4c&urls=http://theweeklyworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/child-happy-face1.jpg&attributes=all" and I want to do this in my python-script with my image. On their website https://skybiometry.com/documentation/ on point 4.13 they said that the request has to be formed as a MIME if I want to analyze images from my hard disk. I do not know how to handle this. In an other project of mine I have done the request like this

```
import requests     
    auth_headers = {
            'api_key': api_key,
            'api_secret': api_secret,
             }

    url = 'http://api.skybiometry.com/fc/faces/detect'

    files = {   'source': open(path + ".jpg", 'rb')

            }
    data = {    'timeout': 60

           }

response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, headers=auth_headers)

print (response.json())
```

Can anyone help me to adjust this request to make it work?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `api_key` and `api_secret` for your own skybiometry credentials to use that python script.

Anyway, I prefer installing the api client skybiometry first for python and then use your python scripts. To install it you need to follow these steps:

1. `git clone git@github.com:SkyBiometry/python-face-client.git`
2. `cd python-face-client`
3. `python setup.py build`
4. `python setup.py install`

Then you can use the api-client using `import` with your skybiometry credentials, for example:

```
from face_client import FaceClient
client = FaceClient('API_KEY', 'API_SECRET')
```

Changing the `API_KEY` and `API_SECRET` for your own skybiometry credentials.

For more examples and how to use the api-client, you can watch this: https://github.com/SkyBiometry/python-face-client

Greetings.